# Powershell Script in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage

I am new to Azure and Powershell.

I have files in an Azure container and I would like to be able to write in a new file, the list of all the files that are in my container.

I saw that there is "Get-ChildItem" but I do not know how to use it in a container on Azure.

Can you please help me ??

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `Get-AzureStorageBlob` cmdlet, like so:

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container containerName -Context (Create context here)
```

More examples:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-powershell-guide-full#create-a-storage-account
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell